# MS SQL Server select statement: display all combinations from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in a MS SQL Server database:

Table1

```
  Emp_ID, First_Name, Last_Name
  1 Joe Smith
  2 Bob Jones
```

Table2

```
  Emp_ID, Dept_ID, Status
  1 1   Active
  1 2   NotActive
  1 3   NotActive
  2 1   Active
```

What I would like to do is create a SQL select statement that displays a row for every employee and department combination along with the status even if the employee has never been in the department (table 2). For the sample data, this should bring back 6 records since there are 2 employees and 3  departments.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: use a cross join to generate a Cartesian of all rows from one table to all rows in another  `SELECT * FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB`  older style syntax would be `SELECT * FROM TableA, TableB` but I would stick with cross join to follow a more current standard.  Join Help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: xQbert - but if I do a cross join how do I get it to display the correct status from table2 when there is a match between emp_id on both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a `departments` table, you'll need to create a subquery to get the `distinct` list of `dept_ids` to `cross join` on:

```
select emp_id, first_name, last_name, dept.dept_id, status
from empl
  cross join (select distinct dept_id from empdept) dept
  left join empdept on empl.emp_id = empdept.empt_id  
                   and dept.dept_id = empdept.dept_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3411a/1)

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect. I appreciate the fiddler demo too!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1  T1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.EMP_ID=T2.EMP_ID
```